# hiding jqgrid with knockout break it (jquery issue?)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, knockout.js

```
<div data-bind="ifnot: SelectedElement">
    test
    <table id="elementsTable" class="scroll">
    </table>
</div>

<div data-bind="with: SelectedElement">
    <p data-bind="text: Id"></p>
    <p data-bind="text: Name"></p>
    <p data-bind="text: Description"></p>

    <button data-bind="click: $parent.CloseElement">Close</button>
</div>
```

Code above hide a jqGrid to show Element details and allow to close it and show jqGrid at previus state - but after closing element jqGrid disaper I could always call again initGrid() but that is not the best solution. Is there any workaround to do that? creating element with absolute position isn't the best choice (will cause some design issue propably)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, small workaround instead using databind I use jquery show/hide - this preserve jqGrid untouched.